# Gradio - remove the tagline

Tags: gradio

Gradio includes a tagline "built with gradio".  How can I remove that?

If for some reason this option was omitted, is there a monkey patch that can do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access the footer via css and make it hidden:

```css
footer {visibility: hidden}
```

Used in the following hello world example, makes "built with gradio" hidden.

```py
import gradio as gr

def greet(name):
    return "Hello " + name + "!"

demo = gr.Interface(
    fn=greet,
    inputs="text",
    outputs="text",
    css="footer {visibility: hidden}"
)
demo.launch()
```

Comment: how to change footer to like <Built with Gradio> to <Build with zzzzz>.

Answer (score 4):

Extending on the accepted answer - 
If you want to remove the "built with gradio" footer when using Gradio Blocks, pass the CSS Blocks:
 `gr.Blocks(css=css)`

Answer (score 3):

To remove the footer:

[image]

[abidlabs](https://github.com/abidlabs) [mentioned](https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio/issues/2510#issuecomment-1287096988) one can add `css="footer{display:none !important}"` in `gr.Interface`. Example:

```
import gradio as gr

def greet(name):
    return "Hello " + name + "!"

demo = gr.Interface(fn=greet, inputs="text", outputs="text", 
                    css="footer{display:none !important}")

demo.launch()
```

`css="footer{display:none !important}"` can also be added in `gr.Blocks`. Example:

```
import gradio as gr

def dummy(a):
    return "hello", {"hell": "o"}

with gr.Blocks(css="footer{display:none !important}") as demo:
    # Define buttons
    txt = gr.Textbox(value="test", label="Query", lines=1)
    answer = gr.Textbox(value="", label="Answer")
    with gr.Row():
        btn = gr.Button(value="Submit")
        clear_btn = gr.ClearButton()
    answerjson = gr.JSON()

    # Define button actions
    btn.click(dummy, inputs=[txt], outputs=[answer, answerjson])
    clear_btn.add([answer, answerjson])

demo.launch(share=True)
```

UI:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here's official solution:

```
gradio.Interface(allow_flagging="never")
```

allow_flagging: this parameter can be set to either "manual" default), "auto", or "never".
m

- anual: users will see a button to flag, and samples are only flagged
  when the button is clicked.
- auto: users will not see a button to
  flag, but every sample will be flagged automatically.
- never: users
  will not see a button to flag, and no sample will be flagged.

Reference: https://www.gradio.app/guides/using-flagging